# Omit an object with certain deep values from another object

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparison, javascript-objects

I'm trying to omit `req.body` data, when updating a resource in a collection, with only the fields that are `null` or `''` for that existing resource in the collection.

But this could also be generic, that's why the title is more generic.

Anyways, imagine the following:

We have a user in our database with the following data:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "address": {
    "Address1": "Random street 1",
    "City": "",
    "Country": null
  },
  "email": ""
}
```

The user is trying to update the existing resource with the following data:

```
{
  "firstName": "Mark",
  "address": {
    "Address1": "Random street 2",
    "City": "NY",
    "Country": "USA"
  },
  "email": "john.doe@mail.com"
}
```

**Updated object** should like like this:

```
{
  "firstName": "John", // Unchanged because propety value already exists
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "address": {
    "Address1": "Random street 1", // Unchanged because propety value already exists
    "City": "NY", // Updated because existing value is empty ("")
    "Country": "USA" // Updated because existing value is null
  },
  "email": "john.doe@mail.com" // Updated because existing value is empty ("")
}
```

I'm using mongoose, but I would rather implement this on the basic javascript object level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any library but below is the working example using recursion.

```js
var oldObj = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "address": {
    "Address1": "Random street 1",
    "City": "",
    "Country": null
  },
  "email": ""
}

var newObj = {
  "firstName": "Mark",
  "address": {
    "Address1": "Random street 2",
    "City": "NY",
    "Country": "USA"
  },
  "email": "john.doe@mail.com"
}

updateObject(oldObj, newObj);


function updateObject(oldObj, newObj) {
  Object.keys(oldObj).forEach( key => {
    if (oldObj[key] && typeof oldObj[key] === 'object') {
      updateObject(oldObj[key], newObj[key]);
    } else {
      oldObj[key] = oldObj[key] || newObj[key];
    }
  });
}

console.log("Modified Obj: ", oldObj);
```

Hope this may help you.